# Ajax Onchange replace div not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a select box with onchange,

```
<select class="form-control"  onchange="getval(this.value,'<?php echo $prd->pr_id;?>','ajax<?php echo $key?>','<?php  echo $key ?>')">
```

and my ajax div is in foreach loop,

```
foreach($name as $names)
{
<div id = "ajax<?php echo $key?>" Some Content </div>
}
```

My ajax function:

```
function getval(id,prid,divid,key)
{  
alert(divid)

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "aid="+id+"&prid="+prid,
        url: '<?php echo site_url('grocery/onchange')?>',
        success: function(html){
        $('#'+divid).html(html);

        };
    });
}
```

i am tryimg to change the div content..but its not working?

Comment: it should be foreach($name as $key => $names)

Comment: it was came from another foreach.

Comment: which error u getting in console? also change url to '<?php echo site_url("grocery/onchange")?>' and in foreach change line to <div id = "ajax<?php echo $key?>" > Some Content </div>

Comment: there is a > missing i think in div
<div id = "ajax<?php echo $key?>" >

Comment: changed but nothing happens.. :(

Comment: also, you shouldn't use alert while using ajax use `console.log()` instead. And I suspect the parameters also you can directly pass parameters as- `{aid:id,prid:prid}`

Answer (score 0):

You need a lot of changes in your ajax-

first use `console.log()` instead of alert and then because your div's `id(s)` are being created dynamically then you need to handle it in this way-

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {aid:id,prid:prid},
        url: '<?php echo site_url('grocery/onchange')?>',
        success: function(html){
          $(document).find('div[id='+divid+']').html(html);
     };
  });
```

Here is the live example- http://jsfiddle.net/x4Lvfk9k/

Comment: does it hit the method at `grocery/onchange`? if yes then does it come back to success?